# What is the best library for Roles & Permissions in Spring backend project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on Java Spring backend project that it provides RESTful service for many applications (Web, Mobile). For now, I want to integrate Roles and Permissions in to the backend project.

Please give me some your suggestion about best lib/framework for user roles & permissions. Examples: AspectJ, Apache Shiro, ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since you have spring frame work in your project why don't you go ahead with spring security (for user authentication and autherization)

Answer (score 1):

Use spring security. You can follow the below link.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security will be good choice.

You can decide roles and even you can restrict roles to use rest end point methods.

Easy to embed and as annotation architecture evolved lot you can configure spring security with not or little xml configuration.